# Cannot Access Proxmox GUI After Create Linux Bridge Network

Tags: proxmox

Good Morning!
I have a baremetal server on equinix with gateway CIDR /31 (default) then I bought a new Gateway with CIDR /28 after that I connected to the server, but after installing proxmox and I created a linux bridge vmbr0 and put all IP Gateway /28 into vmbr0 but after i restarted i can't access server and Web GUI.

```
IPv4 Base: 86.109.11.235
CIDR: 86.109.11.234/31
Gateway: 86.109.11.234

Attach IP
IPv4: 147.75.109.178
CIDR: 147.75.109.176/28
Gateway: 147.75.109.177

$ root@elk: cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto bond0
iface bond0 internet static
     address 86.109.11.235
     netmask 255.255.255.254
     gateway 86.109.11.234
     bond-down delay 200
     bond-miimon 100
     bond-mode 4
     bond-update 200
     bond-xmit_hash_policy layer3+4
     bond-slaves ens6f0 ens6f1 ens6f2 ens6f3
     dns-nameservers 147.75.207.207 147.75.207.208
iface bond0 inet6 static
     address 2604:1380:45e1:de00::1
     netmask 127
     gateway 2604:1380:45e1:de00::

auto bond0:0
iface bond0:0 inet static
     address 10.67.52.1
     netmask 255.255.255.254
     post-up route add -net 10.0.0.0/32 gw 10.67.52.0
     post-down route del -net 10.0.0.0/32 gw 10.67.52.0
```

[Network GUI Proxmox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQzJ9.png)